# How to alter and update primary key of mysql table which is used as uuid (char(36)) to bigint having foreign key and exists huge data

Tags: php, mysql

I have table mTable(page_id,parent_page_id,,,). Page_id and parent_page_id are char(36) uuid(). And also have children tables linked with mTable with key Page_id. I used Inno_db_per_table. After inserting records the size of database is grown upto 12 gb of all tables (mTable and its Children).

Now my problem is that when i want to do any alteration in tables it hangs and mostly mysqld.exe stopped working.
I want to change this primary key and also want to update the base table so that automatically the children table's keys updated efficiently.

Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: How much memory do have allocated for MySQL?

Comment: You need drop the `FOREIGN` constraint before make the updates to PK and FK

Comment: Thank You Very "wogsland" much for response. I use windows xp, with 2gb. I don't know how to allocate memory specially to mysql.

Comment: I have tried the same with command "alter table ? disable keys;". but facing problem yet.

Comment: Please suggest if I m doing well or wrong by using uuid() as primary key. I am not getting performance even a single bit.